# Confused with hoisting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Can anyone explain to me why `if` statement inside of `bar` has `foo` us undefined?

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This foo is at the global level.
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
  // the compiler puts in this line:
    var foo;
    if (!foo) {
        // and the var here doesn't matter.
        foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

Answer (score 2):

The given code will be parsed like this:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    var foo;
    if (!foo) {
        foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

The local foo is hoisted to the top of the function since JS only has function scope and no block scope. The "hoisted" variable will take precedence over the foo defined outside the function, which is why the variable is undefined in your if statement.